# Difference between a 'figure' and 'figurine'?

Tags: meaning

I am writing a product description for an Easter bunny decorative figure/figurine and I am stuck at which term to use for my copy as both these terms have been used interchangeably on different sites.

Comment: @Hank the answer is not as simple as that. Sense 10 & 10a of the word *figure* per the OED is *10. esp. An artificial representation of the human form. a. In sculpture: A statue, an image, an effigy.* it is clearly from the French and has examples from 1300. However *figurine*, also from French, starts to appear only in 1854. Sounds like it has an association with 19th century romanticism, but I don't know enough about art history to comment further. it could be to do with the size. *Figurine* per OED is *A small carved or sculptured figure.*

Comment: Generally speaking, a figurine is the actual physical object whereas figure is what it represents.

Comment: @Lambie That's what I was trying to convey in my original comment. Typical usage, not absolute usage.

Comment: @Hank I guess you deleted it? I actually did not see it but I believe you. :)

Comment: @Lambie I did. I didn't feel like getting into the specifics so I opted out lol. Plus, the first answer was close to my comment so it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @Lambie That may well be how the two words are nowadays used, and I think you should record it as an answer. For though Silenus' answer is accurate so far as it goes, and I upvoted it, it does not hit on that particular point. Nonetheless it still needs to be borne in mind that in all the centuries of art prior to 1854, people seem to have managed without the word *figurine*.

Answer (score 3):

*Figure* and *figurine* can be used interchangeably to describe a small statue or statuette.

> ***figure***   a representation of a human or animal form in drawing or sculpture   ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/figure))
>
> ***figurine***   a statuette, especially one of a human form  ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/figurine))

That said, *figure* is a more general term. In the statue sense alone, *figure* connotes no size, whereas *figurine* connotes a smaller size. Furthermore, *figure* has a plethora of other senses, evinced by the dictionary entry linked above.

If you're writing a product description, you should probably go with the more specific term, *figurine*.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I should go with figurine. Thank you

Comment: @Khan Unless your Easter bunny is actually 10 feet tall. Then it's definitely not a figurine!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a figurine is the actual physical object whereas figure is what it represents.

An Easter Bunny figurine = an actual ceramic or ceramic-like little statue of an Easter Bunny

An Easter Bunny figure = a representation of an Easter Bunny.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I believe "figurine" is correct.  The word "figurine" basically means: a small statue. Although, classically speaking, it refers to a statue of a human, or the human form; it has come to also refer to small decorative pieces.  It does, however, need to be in the likeness of something of someone.  A decorative vase, for example, is generally not considered a "figurine". A small statue of a child, a character like Mickey Mouse or SpongeBob, or the Easter Bunny would qualify.

Comment: But you have omitted to say how *figurine* differs in meaning from *figure*.

Comment: And ELU vastly prefers answers backed up by supporting references.